# What is the difference between finding the threshold and training a binary classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, threshold

I have 1-D data: the output of a Cosine similarity (COS) distance between two features. The data is bounded by [-1,1].

When I just try to find the optimum threshold for class labels - I get an accuracy for the testing data of about 75%

Then I thought to maybe train a binary classifier (namely wx+b - 1 layer of linear fully connected and pass it to a sigmoid and then to binary loss function)
When I do the following I get only 71% accuracy.

What do you think is the difference between the two approaches? Why is the threshold method get higher accuracy? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very closely related possibly an outright duplicate: [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Comment: I think it quite different, I will try to emphasise the difference, here I am wondering what is the difference between just searching for an optimal margin and applying a linear transformation and a Loss function

Comment: Searching for an "optimal margin" is nothing else than using a particular (implicit) loss function.

Comment: so what in the process do you see wrong? because the results are very different